# The updating for "stat" function is slow?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Code Snippet:

```
void CMyLogger::Log(
    LogLevel level, LPCTSTR file, INT line, LPCTSTR func, LPCTSTR format, ...)
{
    time_t tCurrentLogTime;
    time(&tCurrentLogTime);

    tm tmCurrentLogTime;
    localtime_s(&tmCurrentLogTime, &tCurrentLogTime);

    // Check the date is changed
    if (m_tmCurrentLogTime.tm_year == tmCurrentLogTime.tm_year
        && m_tmCurrentLogTime.tm_mon == tmCurrentLogTime.tm_mon
        && m_tmCurrentLogTime.tm_mday == tmCurrentLogTime.tm_mday)
    {
        // Check the log file size has exceeded the maximum size
        struct _stat st;
        _tstat(m_szCurrentLogFile, &st);
        if (st.st_size > m_nMaxLogSize)
        {
            m_nCurrentLogIndex++;

            GetCurrentLogFile();

            CLogger::ClearOutputStreams();

            // Add logger
            AddOutputStream(new std::tofstream(m_szCurrentLogFile), true, LogLevel::Info);
        }
    }

    // The date is changed
    else
    {
        // Get current log time
        memcpy(&m_tmCurrentLogTime, &tmCurrentLogTime, sizeof(tmCurrentLogTime));

        m_nCurrentLogIndex = 0;

        DeleteOldFiles();
        GetCurrentLogFile();

        CLogger::ClearOutputStreams();

        // Add logger
        AddOutputStream(new std::tofstream(m_szCurrentLogFile), true, LogLevel::Info);
    }


    // Log
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    int length = _vsctprintf(format, args ) + 1;
    TCHAR* text =  new TCHAR[length];
    _vstprintf_s(text, length, format, args);
    va_end(args);

    CLogger::Log(level, file, line, func, text);

    delete [] text;
}
```

The above is a code snippet of log program. If the log file exceeds to 1 MB, create new log file. (xxx_000.log => xxx_001.log ...) I write the following code to test whether new log file is created when the log file exceeds to 1 MB:

```
#ifdef UNICODE
#define LOG(level, format, ...) CEagleLogger::GetInstance()->Log(level, __FILEW__, __LINE__, __FUNCTIONW__, format, __VA_ARGS__);
#else
#define LOG(level, format, ...) CEagleLogger::GetInstance()->Log(level, __FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__, format, __VA_ARGS__);
#endif

// ...

while (1)
    LOG(LogLevel::Info, _T("================================================================================"));
```

But, the log files are not created every 1 MB. The log file size is checked to `stat` function before write log. When actual log file size is exceeded to 1 MB, the 'stat' function is not exceed to 1 MB. The updating for "stat" function is slow?

[image: The log size is different.]

Comment: Define "does not seem to have the current file size correctly."

Comment: The `stat` function goes directly to the OS to query state about the file.  Are you using buffered I/O to write the log file and, if so, have you flushed the buffer before calling `stat`?

Comment: std::tostream * stream = iter->m_stream;
(*stream) << _T("[");
(*stream) << text;
(*stream) << _T("]");
write<LPCTSTR>(stream, text);
(*stream) << std::endl;
stream->flush(); In the last sentence, I use the flush function.

Comment: `endl` already flushes.

Comment: Is it possible that you are simply writing really long `text` values at times? Unless `std::tostream` (which BTW is NOT a standard class, so it does not belong in the `std` namespace) is internally doing its own file size calculations while it is flushing, then there is nothing in that code to break up log files at/near the 1MB boundary.  Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: I know about `std::endl` but it unfortunately is typically misused to I strongly recommend to use `std::flush` where a flush is really meant.

Comment: You may argue that `std::endl` is misused, i.e. that usually `\n` is intended (no flush), but I don't see how that becomes an argument for `std::flush`. After all, the problem is too many flushes, not too little.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis: This is Windows code; `_tstat` is VC++ CRT code (not the OS). I checked the CRT implementation, it calls `FindFirstFile` which returns the directory entry information which is updated only on file close (since Vista)

Comment: Yes, it is slow, the OS is just not in a hurry to update the directory entry while the file is being written to.  Use the stream's `tellp()` function instead.

Comment: @MSalters:  When I said that it "goes directly to the OS," I meant that it ends up querying the OS directly for the information, so if there was still any data buffered, it might not be reflected.  I did not mean that `_stat`/`_wstat` are implemented by the operating system itself (but I can see how my comment could be confusing).  I did not know that the file size information is only reflected on file close; thanks for that information. (I guess I did know this, from watching files be written on Windows, but I didn't put two and two together until reading your comment...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stat` is a POSIX function. `_tstat` is a Windows function intended to help porting POSIX code to Windows (but the _t stuff hinders porting the other way). Don't expect the best performance from such wrappers.

In particular, `stat` is the equivalent of `FindFirstFile` on Windows, and the CRT code included with Visual Studio confirms this: the first system call in `_stat` is to `FindFirstFileEx(FindExInfoStandard ... FindExSearchNameMatch)`. . It gives you a number of properties of a directory entry, including the file size *in the directory*. For a file that's being written, that information is out of date. [`GetFileSize` has the correct size](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/12/26/10251026.aspx)

(Note that `_stat` is also doing quite a bit of work to get all kinds of properties that you don't even want. That was pretty cheap on UNIX, but on Windows the file access rights stuff has to be emulated. Not fast either.)